# Old anime where the protagonist was climbing a mountain or tower and fighting demons

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching an old anime where the protagonist was a boy.

In episode 1, he was climbing a mountain or tower (also, by "he was climbing", think of him being on the edge of a mountain or tower climbing like hiking), and he was fighting either corrupted souls, demons, or ghosts.

His companion was a girl fighting with a double dagger or guns or scythe. Also, the protagonist was probably either exorcising them or destroying them.

That is the only information I can give since I do not remember.